# Есть список со мнжеством значений, нужно создать словарь по уникальным значениям

Tags: python, list, dict, преобразование

У меня есть список. Кусок из него:

```
Timestamp: 1675240149.800284    ID: 00002000    X Rx                DL:  3    0f 00 66 66 66 0b 3f 8c     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.802410    ID: 00002001    X Rx                DL:  8    05 7a 02 88 05 84 05 7f     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.804286    ID: 00002004    X Rx                DL:  8    80 00 00 2a 00 00 00 00     Channel: can0
 00 00 00 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.859962    ID: 00003005    X Rx                DL:  8    0b 1e 05 16 14 0a 00 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.896405    ID: 00002000    X Rx                DL:  8    0f 00 66 66 66 0b 3f 8a     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.898284    ID: 00002001    X Rx                DL:  8    05 d2 02 86 05 d0 05 d7     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.906460    ID: 00002004    X Rx                DL:  8    80 00 00 2a 00 00 00 00     Channel: can0
```

В данном списке повторяются значения id. Как по уникальным id составить словарь, в котором значения id - это ключи, а все остальные строки, содержащие этот же уникальный id, это значения.

Comment: Между параметрами табуляция или пробелы?

Comment: Если есть нормальный разделитель(\t) то я бы прогнал через csv

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм будет такой:

1. Создать пустой словарь `{}`
2. Идти последовательно по строкам
3. Выделять `ID` из строки с помощью регулярного выражения
4. Если `ID` в строке не найден - строка, видимо, пропускается (уточнить этот момент)
5. Если в словаре нет ключа, равного найденному `ID`, то добавляем в словарь элемент с таким ключом и значением пустой список `[]`
6. Берём в словаре элемент по `ID` (это будет список) и делаем ему `.append(строка)`

Код думаю сами набросаете, тут ничего сложного.

Comment: defaultdict для упрощения пунктов 4,5

Comment: @eri Да, я его и сам люблю, но писать алгоритм словами с ним как-то сложнее )

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '''
Timestamp: 1675240149.800284    ID: 00002000    X Rx                DL:  3    0f 00 66 66 66 0b 3f 8c     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.802410    ID: 00002001    X Rx                DL:  8    05 7a 02 88 05 84 05 7f     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.804286    ID: 00002004    X Rx                DL:  8    80 00 00 2a 00 00 00 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.859962    ID: 00003005    X Rx                DL:  8    0b 1e 05 16 14 0a 00 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.896405    ID: 00002000    X Rx                DL:  8    0f 00 66 66 66 0b 3f 8a     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.898284    ID: 00002001    X Rx                DL:  8    05 d2 02 86 05 d0 05 d7     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1675240149.906460    ID: 00002004    X Rx                DL:  8    80 00 00 2a 00 00 00 00     Channel: can0
'''.strip().split('\n')

d = {}
for line in data:
    id_ = line.split()[3]
    d.setdefault(id_, []).append(line)

for k, v in d.items():
    print('', k, *v, sep='\n')
```

> ```
> 00002000
> Timestamp: 1675240149.800284    ID: 00002000    X Rx                DL:  3    0f 00 66 66 66 0b 3f 8c     Channel: can0
> Timestamp: 1675240149.896405    ID: 00002000    X Rx                DL:  8    0f 00 66 66 66 0b 3f 8a     Channel: can0
>
> 00002001
> Timestamp: 1675240149.802410    ID: 00002001    X Rx                DL:  8    05 7a 02 88 05 84 05 7f     Channel: can0
> Timestamp: 1675240149.898284    ID: 00002001    X Rx                DL:  8    05 d2 02 86 05 d0 05 d7     Channel: can0
>
> 00002004
> Timestamp: 1675240149.804286    ID: 00002004    X Rx                DL:  8    80 00 00 2a 00 00 00 00     Channel: can0
> Timestamp: 1675240149.906460    ID: 00002004    X Rx                DL:  8    80 00 00 2a 00 00 00 00     Channel: can0
>
> 00003005
> Timestamp: 1675240149.859962    ID: 00003005    X Rx                DL:  8    0b 1e 05 16 14 0a 00 00     Channel: can0
> ```